# Best link using 2 vars?

Tags: seo

I have a shop with categories, how much important is to have the category name on the links?

I am using rewriteRules on my .htaccess; for instance:

```
www.someShop/productDetail.php?prodID=1234    
www.someShop/product/category-name/product-name
```

Or

```
www.someShop/productDetail.php?prodID=1234 
www.someShop/product/product-name
```

Is the link with the cat name better?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: second proposition because category name is interesting for user and google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is, urls are one of valuable parts of SEO optimization, if you have category name in your product url search engines easily detect category name of your product and this affect in final result of search

in another view when users see your site link in search engines, they can found out what is category of this product, and it help them to go to right link

Comment: I ended with: www.someShop/product/1234/category-name/product-name. Is it ok to leave the product number? (1234), this will be the id I need to get the info on the database.

Comment: it's ok, look this page url, stackoverflow has question number in url too ;)